# onBindViewHolder() called only once Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, android-recyclerview, adapter

In my code onBindViewHolder() called only once even the list size is great than one. I have gone through many SO questions but those answer is not helpful in my case. Only one item is visible in view.

getItemCount() returning the exact list size ie 5  but onBindViewHolder() called only once.

Adapter

```
class AddressListAdapter internal constructor(
    private val viewModel: MeineDatenViewModel
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AddressListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var data = arrayListOf<Adressen>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder =
            ViewHolder(
                    LayoutMyDataAddressItemBinding.inflate(
                            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false
                    )
            )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        data.add(viewModel.getAddressesList(position))
        holder.bind(position)
    }

    inner class ViewHolder internal constructor(private var meinedatenListItemAddressBinding: LayoutMyDataAddressItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(meinedatenListItemAddressBinding.root) {

        internal fun bind(position: Int) {
            meinedatenListItemAddressBinding.address = data[position]
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return viewModel.getAddressesListCount()
    }
}
```

List item :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mb_corpo_s_textoffice_bold"
                android:text="@{validSince}"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/global_label_text_size_17sp"
                android:visibility="@{validSince == null ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
                tools:text="gültig ab 22.02.2003" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mb_corpo_s_textoffice_regular"
                android:text="@{address.adresse1}"
                android:textSize="@dimen/global_label_text_size_17sp"
                tools:text="Hauptstraße 3" />
            
    </LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerView :

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/meine_daten_address_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    />
```

Fragment :

```
addressListAdapter = AddressListAdapter(myDataViewModel)
 binding?.meineDatenAddressList?.adapter = addressListAdapter
```

ViewModel:

```
val addresses: LiveData<ArrayList<Adressen>> = Transformations.map(employeeDataLiveData) { employeeData ->
        val addresses = ArrayList<Adressen>()

        if (employeeData?.adressen != null) {
            addresses.addAll(employeeData.adressen)
            addresses.sortWith(Comparator { a1: Adressen, a2: Adressen ->
                val date1 = DateFormatter.yyyyMMdd(a1.stichtag)
                val date2 = DateFormatter.yyyyMMdd(a2.stichtag)

                date1.compareTo(date2)
            })

            if (addresses.size >= 2 && "Aktuell" == addresses[0].status && "Aktuell" == addresses[1].status) {
                addresses.removeAt(0)
            }
        }
        Timber.d("address ab list %s", addresses.size)
        return@map addresses
    }

    fun getAddressesListCount() : Int{
        return addresses.value?.size ?: 0
    }

    fun getAddressesList(index:Int) : Adressen {
        return Adressen(addresses.value?.get(index)?.addressart, addresses.value?.get(index)?.addressartid, addresses.value?.get(index)?.adresse1, addresses.value?.get(index)?.adresse2, addresses.value?.get(index)?.adresse3, addresses.value?.get(index)?.adresse4, addresses.value?.get(index)?.adresseLang, addresses.value?.get(index)?.bundesland, addresses.value?.get(index)?.county, addresses.value?.get(index)?.hausart, addresses.value?.get(index)?.land, addresses.value?.get(index)?.landid, addresses.value?.get(index)?.postleitzahl, addresses.value?.get(index)?.stadt, addresses.value?.get(index)?.status, addresses.value?.get(index)?.statusID, addresses.value?.get(index)?.stichtag)
    }
```

Please help me out where I am wrong.

Note : List item root tag is already wrap content.

Comment: have u defined layoutmanager for your recyclerview?

Comment: @Ankit yes have added in xml only

Comment: Pass your list to the constructor of adapter and then use that list. instead of passing viewmodel.

Comment: @Ankit tried as you suggested but only 1 item is visible in list.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your adapter like this

```
   class AddressListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<AddressListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var data = arrayListOf<Adressen>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder =
            ViewHolder(
                    LayoutMyDataAddressItemBinding.inflate(
                            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false
                    )
            )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = data[position]
        holder.bind(item)
    }

    inner class ViewHolder internal constructor(private var meinedatenListItemAddressBinding: LayoutMyDataAddressItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(meinedatenListItemAddressBinding.root) {

        internal fun bind(item: Adressen) {
            meinedatenListItemAddressBinding.address = item.toString()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.count()
  
    fun setData(data: ArrayList<Adressen>){
        this.data = data
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

in your fragment call

```
addressListAdapter = AddressListAdapter()
binding?.meineDatenAddressList?.adapter = addressListAdapter
myDataViewModel.addresses.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){addresses->
 addressListAdapter.setData(addresses)     
}
```

Comment: Still onBindViewHolder() called only once. Pass list through constructor. Only 1 item is visible in list.

Comment: show getAddressesListCount() function from viewmodel

Comment: Have updated in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: sorry to say but still I can see only one item. All items are not visible.